# Using Javascript within Splinter to change a value for an element of known ID

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, browser, splinter

I am quite new to python. I'm trying to extract data from a website and I need to set dates for a data search. The dates are set via date pickers and I cannot fill the forms using splinter element.fill(). However, I know the element names and the date is stored as its value which should be changeable.

Since I've never used javascript I'm not sure what the syntax is. I hoped something like:

browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('fromdate').value=10.12.2019")

would work, but I run into issues. Could somebody offer some help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this code should work, but I think you missed the quotes. Please try something like this:

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("fromdate").value="10.12.2019"')
```